# Android WIFI UDP Messages Huawei / Honor Specific Issue

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, networking, udp

I have UDP based application which is working fine with all other android devices except **Huawei and Honor** phones.

I have used below things

```
udpSocket = DatagramSocket(port, ipAddress)
udpSocket?.broadcast = true
udpSocket?.reuseAddress = true
Log.e("TAG", "UDP Open : " + ipAddress?.toString() + " Port : ${udpSocket?.localPort}")
```

`udpSocket = DatagramSocket(port, ipAddress)`: This line creates a new DatagramSocket instance and binds it to the specified port. A DatagramSocket is a UDP socket used for sending and receiving UDP packets.

`udpSocket?.broadcast = true`: This line sets the socket's broadcast property to true. This allows the socket to send UDP broadcast packets.

`udpSocket?.reuseAddress = true`: This line sets the socket's reuseAddress property to true. This allows the socket to reuse a local address even if it is in a TIME_WAIT state, which is helpful in certain scenarios.

Reading data continuedly using thread.

```
Thread(Runnable {
    Log.e("TAG", "UDP@startListen Thread")
    while (udpSocket != null) {
        if (lastExTime == -1L) {
            lastExTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        //Log.e("TAG", "UDP@startListen Thread Loop #1")
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        Log.e(
            TAG,
            "Packet Len : " + packet.length + " Data Size " + packet.data.size + " OffSet : " + packet.getOffset() + " Interval : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastExTime)
        )
        lastExTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        var pExTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        receivePacket(packet)
        Log.e(TAG, "Packet Receive Time :" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - pExTime))
        handlePacket(packet)
    }
    Log.e("TAG", "UDP@startListen Thread Loop End")
    listeningStarted = false
    udpSocket?.close()
}).start()
```

The code sets up a UDP packet listening process running in a separate thread. It continuously receives UDP packets, logs information about the packets, measures the time taken to receive each packet, and then processes the received packets. The listening process runs until the UDP socket is set to null, and the thread is responsible for closing the socket when the process ends.

> **Issue is only with Huawei devices and their EMUI OS's, Any Idea ?**